# ctags: underscore for filename and zero for source line: which variant is this?

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags, universal-ctags

In the source of an application, I am seeing multiple tags files, with underscores in place of the file name and zero in place of the source line number or regex address. I’m not used to CTags, so looked at the different format known, that is, the original ctags, exuberant ctags and universel ctags (there is also a ctags universal which seems a bit different). Unless I unfortunately overlooked the documentation, I failed to find a statement about this.

Here is a sample from one of these tags files:

```
string  _   0;" M   
Formatter   _   0;" f   class:string
Template    _   0;" f   class:string
```

Do someone know if this is valid in any known ctags variant and if it is, is this me who overlooked the documentations, if it is not, which is this variant and where can I read its specification?

— Édit —

I guess this is used for word completion, but still wonder if it is as intended by the ctags dialects and if editors using ctags expect this. But this is still just a guess, I am not sure.

Comment: What kind of command line do you use to run ctags?

Comment: None, I found these files among other files of the source of an application. But may be this is just a hack.